# Xcode ignoring Other Linker Flags

Tags: xcode, linker

In my current project I am unable to set the "Other Linker Flags" as I have in others projects. No matter what I put in the "Other Link Flags" section of my xcode project settings it does not show up in the detailed build log, and the desired linking does not happen:

[image: Other Link Flags]

> Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app/MyProject normal i386
>   cd /Users/theUser/Development/xm8vc/MyProject/trunk
>   setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>   setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk -L/Users/theUser/Development/xm8vc/MyProject/trunk/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/theUser/Development/xm8vc/MyProject/trunk -F/Users/theUser/Development/xm8vc/MyProject/trunk/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/theUser/Development/xm8vc/MyProject/trunk -filelist /Users/theUser/Development/xm8vc/MyProject/trunk/build/MyProject.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyProject.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -lxml2 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -framework QuartzCore -framework AVFoundation -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenGLES -framework CFNetwork -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MediaPlayer -lxml2 -lz -framework SpeechKit -o /Users/theUser/Development/xm8vc/MyProject/trunk/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProject.app/MyProject

Is there something that would cause xcode to ignore the "Other Linker Flags?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where are you setting these flags?  You can set flags like this at various levels in your project - project settings, target settings, etc.  There's a full description in [Working with Xcode Build Settings](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/xcodebuildsettings.html).  It's possible that, for example, you are setting it in your project settings, and then it is being overridden by your target settings.

Comment: That's it thanks! I knew it was something that I was doing wrong, but had run out of places to look.